How do you say "table editor" (a software name) in Latin?
I want to know how to say "table editor" (a software) in Latin.
I have searched that "table" is "mensa" or "tabula" in Latin on Wiktionary but it doesn't mention it means tabular data. Which is preferred?
Does "editor" in Latin mean an editor even which is not a human?

I assume you mean a software that modifies a table rather than publishing it. The English word "edit" means both or mostly the former in modern use but the original Latin means only the latter. Although editor is a valid word, it's unlikely to mean what you want.
